# Large real-world graphs for teaching use?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, teaching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [graphs from real-life problems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/graphs-from-real-life-problems)

I'm teaching Algorithms for the 7th time or so, and I want augment the class by asking the students to implement some of our thematic algorithms on large graphs.  I could of course just generate random graphs and ask them to find the diameter, shortest paths, strongly-connected components, etc.  But I think it would be more interesting to them if I had a real-world graph derived from news, media, Facebook, or any source that would be familiar to them.

The graphs should be large enough that algorithmic efficiency matters, but not so large that they cannot be handled by commodity computers (ie, they must fit in 1GB of memory).

Comment: Moderator notice: the answers/comments/... are moved to the duplicate question as a result of merging.