# Dominating set problem

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for websites or articles where can I find a data with test graphs for domination set problem. In my heuristic algorithms I use undirected and unweighted graphs. So I search for some graphs which already have been tested from other people.

Comment: I cannot see any research level statement in the question, but on the other hand when I saw a question I did a google search to see if deserves to downvote, but I didn't find any reference as requested (in quick search), so I think while the question is not well explained, it's also not very welcome to downvote a new user without any explanation.

Comment: You can search hard instances of problems which can be easily reduced to dominating set. For example search "DIMACS graph benchmarks vertex cover".

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi, That's a good idea, then may be is not bad to explain it in more details as answer (e.g by mentioning that it's approximation or heuristic preserving reduction), e.g I personally had no idea about the good search term for the case that OP looking for, but your suggestion seems to be nice. Well, as I said question is not well explained and we don't know what is the OP's algorithm (approximation, heuristic, exact), but your suggestion is nice anyway.

Comment: @Saeed: I'll wait OP's clarifications :)

Comment: This is a serious research question. Many query complexity problems can be formulated as DOM sets. I had to roll my own C code for MinDomSet. Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question correctly, but you might want to check out this link: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/739/data-for-testing-graph-algorithms

Comment: @Saeed My algorithms are heuristics. I would like to analyze if my heuristics give me results like other algorithms for minimal dominanting set. So I looking for some graphs which already have been tested from other people.

Comment: @AlexGolovnev I am looking if there exists some graphs from other people who tested domination set on it.

Comment: @hans I can guess this but is not clear from ur question. So edit it. Also mention that what did u already found and why databases in others comment is not suitable for you. Write them all in your question.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search revealed [Experiments on Data Reduction for Optimal Domination in Networks](http://theinf1.informatik.uni-jena.de/publications/domset-reduction-annor05.pdf). If you look at their tables they cite a number of data sets for which the actual dominating set is given. They also use a number of random graph generators and publish the average dominating set size for these.

There's another paper from 2002: [Experimental Analysis of Heuristic Algorithms for the Dominating Set Problem](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00453-001-0101-z). I couldn't find an online copy, but I'm sure this paper also documents data sets and actual DS sizes.